# Cannot detect who is taking a lot of disk space on Centos

Tags: centos, disk-space-utilization

I am running out of disk space on a server where I am running tomcat with one Java application. No database on this machine.

I am using CentOS Linux 7 (Core) with Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64

This is my disk space situation:

```
df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   37G   37G   86M 100% /
devtmpfs             3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                3,9G  8,6M  3,9G   1% /run
tmpfs                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           1014M  184M  831M  19% /boot
tmpfs                782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/0
```

This is the list of largest files I can find:

```
du -a /var/ | sort -n -r | head -n 30
239816  /var/
95968   /var/log
75148   /var/cache
74300   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
74300   /var/cache/yum/x86_64
74300   /var/cache/yum
68564   /var/lib
61472   /var/lib/rpm
55856   /var/lib/rpm/Packages
38316   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates
36604   /var/log/audit
34932   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base
32608   /var/log/messages
32108   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/gen/primary_db.sqlite
32108   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/gen
28876   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/gen/primary_db.sqlite
28876   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/gen
23652   /var/log/messages-20180304
8200    /var/log/audit/audit.log.4
8200    /var/log/audit/audit.log.3
8200    /var/log/audit/audit.log.2
8200    /var/log/audit/audit.log.1
6916    /var/lib/yum
6200    /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/6124c600ba0c1509090cbf4b4b33e565c0bd8b9a992285c1cbc1a92815249da9-primary.sqlite.bz2
5888    /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/0c34273ad0292747ee5e15c047d3e51c67ca59861a446972db45d71abacc7ad7-primary.sqlite.bz2
5812    /var/lib/yum/yumdb
3804    /var/log/audit/audit.log
2060    /var/log/anaconda
1644    /var/lib/rpm/Providename
1560    /var/lib/rpm/Basenames
```

And also:

```
du -hs /
du: cannot access ‘/proc/9446/task/9446/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/9446/task/9446/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/9446/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/9446/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
2,4G    /
```

Rebooting did not change the situation significantly (only a few additional MB). So, I tried  `lsof | grep -i delet` and found out closing Tomcat could have helped, as the `catalina.out` file I deleted was still taking space. I stopped and restarted Tomcat, and now the situation is

```
df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   37G   36G  1,8G  96% /
devtmpfs             3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                3,9G  8,6M  3,9G   1% /run
tmpfs                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           1014M  184M  831M  19% /boot
tmpfs                782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/1000


lsof | grep -i delet
firewalld  678             root    6u      REG              253,0      4096   17241411 /tmp/ffiAcnGbQ (deleted)
gmain      678  779        root    6u      REG              253,0      4096   17241411 /tmp/ffiAcnGbQ (deleted)
tuned      946             root    7u      REG              253,0      4096   17241409 /tmp/ffiQ3hRrZ (deleted)
gmain      946 1532        root    7u      REG              253,0      4096   17241409 /tmp/ffiQ3hRrZ (deleted)
tuned      946 1536        root    7u      REG              253,0      4096   17241409 /tmp/ffiQ3hRrZ (deleted)
tuned      946 1541        root    7u      REG              253,0      4096   17241409 /tmp/ffiQ3hRrZ (deleted)
tuned      946 1549        root    7u      REG              253,0      4096   17241409 /tmp/ffiQ3hRrZ (deleted)
```

Just to double check, I used ncdu:

```
  599,3 MiB [####      ] /opt
  297,8 MiB [##        ] /var
  181,0 MiB [#         ] /boot
   68,7 MiB [          ] /tmp
   55,6 MiB [          ] /root
   33,7 MiB [          ] /etc
   16,6 MiB [          ] /run
   80,0 KiB [          ] /home
.   0,0   B [          ] /proc
    0,0   B [          ] /sys
    0,0   B [          ] /dev
@   0,0   B [          ]  lib64
@   0,0   B [          ]  sbin
@   0,0   B [          ]  lib
@   0,0   B [          ]  bin
e   0,0   B [          ] /srv
e   0,0   B [          ] /mnt
e   0,0   B [          ] /media
```

Where is the rest of my disk space?

Edit: one more piece of information

```
cat /proc/self/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,size=3990644k,nr_inodes=997661,mode=755 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/mapper/cl-root / xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=36,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=800276k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its plausible you've got a filesystem mounted over the top of of a directory that contains the used space. I.E /tmp or /var/tmp.

Could you try outputting the result of `cat /proc/self/mounts`?

You could try mounting the root filesystem again in a new path such that there is no filesystems over the top of it.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/tmproot
$ mount /dev/mapper/cl-root /tmp/tmproot
$# Do this to find largest single directories and descend down..
$ du -h --max-depth=1 -x /tmp/tmproot | sort -h
...
$ umount /tmp/tmproot
$ rmdir /tmp/tmproot
```

Alternatively it is plausible the filesystem is damaged in some way and has consumed used inodes without removing the underlying file. I dont know how that logically works between filesystems though.

Hopefully mounting the filesystem in its 'pristine' state may reveal where the files are hidden.

Comment: I edited my OP and added the content of mounts. Unfortunately we are talking about a production server. Is it safe to proceed with re-mounting the root filesystem?

Comment: You're not re-mounting it, you're adding the mountpoint elsewhere in the VFS tree.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I did it, but the output of the du command was the same as before: only 2.4GB appear to be used by tmproot.

Comment: I'd consider running xfs_repair in single user mode with the filesystem in read-only mode. Or rebooting with the kernel parameter ```fsck.mode=force``` to repair the filesystem.

Comment: It's also woth noting that *mounting any file system under `/tmp` is asking for trouble*.  Many systems have a job that periodically spiders down `/tmp` removing any file over a certain age; if that happens to wake up while you've got the root FS re-mounted under `/tmp` things can go very bad very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to check for lost space.

1. Reboot. On unices file removed is not deleted from the disk or
   caches until it's closed by all processes. If you know who can work
   with huge files - restart that process. Check for free space
   changes.
2. When that doesn't help try `du -hs /path/*` to get the list of huge
   folders. Not always the biggest file is the source of problem, but a
   few thousands smaller files can be.

Comment: Unfortunately rebooting did not help. I added the output of the command you suggested to my OP.

Comment: Try ' du -hs /* ' (with the asterisk) - you may find the bulk of your usage is not in /var